# Is $A\in B\left( \overline{H}\right) $ invertible if it is onto and $\left. A\right\vert _{H}\in B\left( H\right) $ is one-to-one and onto?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, inverse-function

Let $\overline{H}$ be a Hilbert space and $A\in B\left( \overline{H}\right) $
be a surjective operator such that $A\left( H\right) =H$ and its restriction
to $H$ is injective and. I'm asking if under these assumptions $A$ in
invertible. All it remains is to show that $A$ is injective, but the problem
is that I don't know how to take a direct complement subspace of $H$ in $\overline{H}$ to construct a bounded inverse of $A$.

To make the assumptions more precise :

1. $H$ is dense in $\overline{H}$.
2. $A\left( \overline{H}\right) =\overline{H}$
3. The restriction operator$\left. A\right\vert _{H}:H\rightarrow H$ is
   invertible, (not necessarily boundedly)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $S$ denote the shift operator acting on $\ell^2(\mathbb{N}_0)$ by
$$S(x_0,x_1,\ldots)=(x_1,x_2,\ldots )$$
Then $S$ is surjective and $S(1,0,\ldots, 0\,\ldots)=0.$
Let $$V={\rm span}\{(\lambda^n)_{n=0}^\infty \,:\, 0<|\lambda|<1\}$$
The space $V$ is dense. Indeed if $v\perp (\lambda^n)$ for any $|\lambda|<1$ then
$$f(\lambda):=\sum_{n=0}^\infty v_n\lambda^n=0,\quad 0<|\lambda|<1$$
The function $f(\lambda)$ is holomorphic, therefore $v_n=0$ for any $n.$
We have $S(V)=V,$ because $S(\lambda^n)_{n=0}^\infty =\lambda (\lambda^n)_{n=0}^\infty.$ The operator $S$ restricted to $V$ is injective as its kernel is one dimensional, and $(1,0,\ldots,0,\ldots)\notin V.$ Indeed
assume
$$(1,0,\ldots,0,\ldots)=a_1(\lambda_1^n)+\ldots +a_k(\lambda_k^n)$$
for distinct numbers $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_k.$
Then $a_1+\ldots +a_k=1$ and $a_1\lambda_1^n+\ldots +a_k\lambda_k^n=0$ for any $n\ge 1.$ The latter implies $a_1+\ldots+a_k=0$ as the Vandermonde determinant of the numbers $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_k$ is nonzero, a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but $A$ is assumed to be bounded, and I asked if it has a bounded inverse under the assumptions. 
What are $\delta_{n}$ and $b_{n}$ precisely ?

Comment: The elements $\delta_n$ form the standard orthonormal basis, consisting of sequences with $1$ at position $n$ and $0$ otherwise. We extend the system $\delta_n$ to the Hamel basis of the entire space and fix a sequence $b_n$ in the additional part of the basis. I missed the requiement of boundedness, sorry. I will remove the answer shortly.

Comment: Thank you very much @Ryszard Szwarc

Comment: Thank you again @Rszard Szwarc

Comment: What a counter-example !!!!